# Error while using the filter method from streams in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am getting an error when I use the filter method. The error says that filter is undefined for the type List. I am not able to figure out if my IDE is not recognizing the filter method or there is some problem with my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have check my compliance level at it says 1.8. Please help me figure out what might be the problem.

```
public class TestJava8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Track track1 = new Track("master1", 7);
    Track track2 = new Track("master2", 8);
    Track track3 = new Track("master3", 9);
    Track track4 = new Track("master4", 10);
    Track track5 = new Track("master5", 11);

    Track track6 = new Track("master6", 7);
    Track track7 = new Track("master7", 8);
    Track track8 = new Track("master8", 9);
    Track track9 = new Track("master9", 10);
    Track track10 = new Track("master10", 11);
    Track track11 = new Track("master11", 12);

    List<Track> tracks1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Track> tracks2 = new ArrayList<>();

    tracks1.add(track1);
    tracks1.add(track2);
    tracks1.add(track3);
    tracks1.add(track4);
    tracks1.add(track5);

    tracks2.add(track6);
    tracks2.add(track7);
    tracks2.add(track8);
    tracks2.add(track9);
    tracks2.add(track10);
    tracks2.add(track11);

    Album album1 = new Album(tracks1);
    Album album2 = new Album(tracks2);

    List<Album> albums = new ArrayList<>();

    albums.add(album1);
    albums.add(album2);

    Set<String> tracksFound = findLongTrackss(albums);

    tracksFound.forEach(track -> System.out.println(track));

}


public static Set<String> findLongTracks(List<Album> albums) {
    Set<String> trackNames = new HashSet<>();
    for (Album album : albums) {
        for (Track track : album.getTracks()) {
            if (track.getLength() > 6) {
                String name = track.getName();
                trackNames.add(name);
            }
        }
    }
    return trackNames;
}

public static Set<String> findLongTrackss(List<Album> albums) {

    Set<String> trackNames = new HashSet<>();

    albums.stream()
    .forEach(album -> {
        album.getTracks()
             .filter(track -> track.getLength() > 8)// I am getting an error here
             .map(track -> track.getName())
             .forEach(name -> trackNames.add(name));
        });

    return trackNames;

}

}
```

Comment: Please make sure your questions contain [mcve] so we don't have to guess what the rest of your code looks like. It looks like `album.getTracks()` returns `List<Track>`.  if that is the case, you should have `.stream()` before `.filter(...)` or else change `getTracks()` to return `Stream<Track>`

Comment: thanks for the advice and answer. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and scroll-down to `Side-Effects`, there is an example really close to yours. You should write your stream as such :

```
Set<String> trackNames = albums.stream()
            .flatMap(a -> a.getTracks().stream()
                    .filter(track -> track.getLength() > 8)
                    .map(Track::getName))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```